# How to remove "Image Information" and "post date/author" from a media page?

Tags: images, author, media, date

I'm trying to use Wordpress to setup a simple website for my business, and I'm having issues with the gallery page. Once an image is clicked and brought to it's specific page, it includes author and post information and as well as image info that I would not like included.

Here is the page in reference: http://hhprintingco.com/our-work/lara-brandt-wedding-invitations-photo/

Previous answers to this question mentioned going to Settings > Media > Caraousel and unchecking the latter. My Settings > Media does not include anything about "Caroaousel".

Much help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Are you referring to the **Posted on December 23, 2013 by admin** links on the top of the page?

Comment: You might look into one of the 80,000 photo gallery plugins. You can skip the whole 'go to another page to see the full sized' image thing with any number of them (most show them on the same page within a lightbox or similar)

Answer (score 1):

Add this CSS code at the end of your child themes style.css file before the Media Queries.

```
.attachment .post-meta {
display: none;
}

.attachment .gallery-meta {
display: none;
}
```

The responsive theme developers do offer a forum for theme customization support questions. http://cyberchimps.com/forum/